# Mostrar formulario en una vista basada en clases de Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Tengo la impresión de que deber ser algo sencillo, pero no consiguo hacerlo con CBV's.  Intento renderizar una vista que muestra el contenido de un post, y a la vez, en la misma vista, mostrar un formulario para que se puedan añadir comentarios al mismo. Lo primero lo tengo, no así lo segundo, mostrar el formulario donde añadir los comentarios. Todas mis vistas son basadas en clases.

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):

    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                           on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('project_list')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

La vista que se supone debe mostrar el formulario para añadir comentarios es muy similar a la vista utilizada para añadir un nuevo tema:

**views.py**

```
class ProjectDetailView(DetailView):
    model = models.Project
    template_name = 'portfolio/project_detail.html'
    fields = ['comment']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

En la plantilla muestro el detalle del post y a la vez intento mostrar el formulario donde añadir comentarios, aquí me pierdo. Si los añado desde el admin los veo, pero no así el formulario.

**p_detail.html**

```
<p>{{ project.description|safe }}</p>


{% for comment in project.comment_set.all %}
<div class="comment">
    {{ comment.body|linebreaks }}
</div>
{% empty %}
<p>There are no comments yet.</p>
{% endfor %}

{% if new_comment %}
  <h2>Your comment has been added.</h2>
{% else %}
<h2>Add a new comment</h2>
<form action="." method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Add comment">    </p>
</form>
{% endif %}
```

y esta es la url con la que muestro el detalle del post

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [

  path('<int:pk>/', views.ProjectDetailView.as_view(),
     name='project_detail'),
```

Gracias anticipadas.

```
       Environment:


    Request Method: POST
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/23/

    Django Version: 2.0.2
    Python Version: 3.6.5
    Installed Applications:
    ['django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'core',
    'users',
    'portfolio.apps.PortfolioConfig']
    Installed Middleware:
    ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



    Traceback:

    File "/home/rni/workspace/pyt/web-personal/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
    35.             response = get_response(request)

    File "/home/rni/workspace/pyt/web-personal/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
    128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

    File "/home/rni/workspace/pyt/web-personal/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
    126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

    File "/home/rni/workspace/pyt/web-personal/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
    69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    File "/home/rni/workspace/pyt/web-personal/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
    89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

    File "/home/rni/workspace/pyt/web-personal/webpersonal/portfolio/views.py" in post
    36.         context = self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

    File "/home/rni/workspace/pyt/web-personal/webpersonal/portfolio/views.py" in get_context_data
    31.         context = super(ProjectDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

    File "/home/rni/workspace/pyt/web-personal/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py" in get_context_data
    93.         if self.object:

    Exception Type: AttributeError at /23/
    Exception Value: 'ProjectDetailView' object has no attribute 'object'
```

Comment: Hola, ¿es esa tu vista completa? No veo, por ejemplo, de dónde sale la variable `new_comment`.

Comment: Hola, no es la vista completa, esa parte la he añadido como prueba. Si no he añadido ningún comentario desde admin, se muestra el mensaje "there are no comments yet", y el botón de añadir comentario, pero ningún campo de formulario.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tu error está en asumir que la clase `DetailView` implementa los métodos `form_valid` o `form_invalid`. Si defines el `form_valid` en tu `ProjectDetailView` simplemente no va a pasar nada porque no hay quien lo llame. A diferencia de `CreateView` y `UpdateView` que implementan el [`ModelFormMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#modelformmixin) (y por lo tanto los métodos antes mencionados), `DetailView` no lo hace ya que es una vista de detalle.

Lo tienes que hacer manualmente dentro de tu CBV:

```
class ProjectDetailView(DetailView):
    model = models.Project
    template_name = 'portfolio/project_detail.html'
    fields = ['comment']
    form_class = CommentForm # O como lo hayas nombrado

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.form_class() 
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        form = self.form_class(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.author = self.request.user
            comment.save()
            return redirect('redirige a algún lado')
        # Si el formulario es inválido, queremos que se muestre en el template
        context['form'] = form
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

La otra cosa que se me ocurre es que tu `ProjectDetailView` herede el mixin `ModelFormMixin`, pero no estoy seguro si funcione. Habría que probarlo.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta. Ahora entiendo porque la vista que tengo para crear contenido con CreateView me lo hace mágicamente. Ya  muestra el formulario, pero ahora tengo que lidiar con que al enviar el comentario me lanza una excepción 'ProjectDetailView' object has no attribute 'object'